# How can I use the for function to stack new rasters?

Tags: raster

I am trying to create a new raster from calculating the difference in values between existing rasters. I want to find the difference between all of the existing rasters and one specific raster. Then, I want to stack all of these rasters. I typed out the entire calculations for 60 rasters, but I want to know the faster way using for.

```
    Change<- stack(
  AMTs$X1950-AMTs$X1950,
  AMTs$X1951-AMTs$X1950,
  AMTs$X1952-AMTs$X1950,
  AMTs$X1953-AMTs$X1950,
  AMTs$X1954-AMTs$X1950,
  AMTs$X1955-AMTs$X1950,
  AMTs$X1956-AMTs$X1950,
  AMTs$X1957-AMTs$X1950,
  AMTs$X1958-AMTs$X1950,
  AMTs$X1959-AMTs$X1950,
AMTs$X1960-AMTs$X1950,
  AMTs$X1961-AMTs$X1950,
  AMTs$X1962-AMTs$X1950,
  AMTs$X1963-AMTs$X1950,
  AMTs$X1964-AMTs$X1950,
  AMTs$X1965-AMTs$X1950,
  AMTs$X1966-AMTs$X1950,
  AMTs$X1967-AMTs$X1950,
  AMTs$X1968-AMTs$X1950,
  AMTs$X1969-AMTs$X1950,
AMTs$X1970-AMTs$X1950,
  AMTs$X1971-AMTs$X1950,
  AMTs$X1972-AMTs$X1950,
  AMTs$X1973-AMTs$X1950,
  AMTs$X1974-AMTs$X1950,
  AMTs$X1975-AMTs$X1950,
  AMTs$X1976-AMTs$X1950,
  AMTs$X1977-AMTs$X1950,
  AMTs$X1978-AMTs$X1950,
  AMTs$X1979-AMTs$X1950,
AMTs$X1980-AMTs$X1950,
  AMTs$X1981-AMTs$X1950,
  AMTs$X1982-AMTs$X1950,
  AMTs$X1983-AMTs$X1950,
  AMTs$X1984-AMTs$X1950,
  AMTs$X1985-AMTs$X1950,
  AMTs$X1986-AMTs$X1950,
  AMTs$X1987-AMTs$X1950,
  AMTs$X1988-AMTs$X1950,
  AMTs$X1989-AMTs$X1950,
AMTs$X1990-AMTs$X1950,
  AMTs$X1991-AMTs$X1950,
  AMTs$X1992-AMTs$X1950,
  AMTs$X1993-AMTs$X1950,
  AMTs$X1994-AMTs$X1950,
  AMTs$X1995-AMTs$X1950,
  AMTs$X1996-AMTs$X1950,
  AMTs$X1997-AMTs$X1950,
  AMTs$X1998-AMTs$X1950,
  AMTs$X1999-AMTs$X1950,
AMTs$X2000-AMTs$X1950,
  AMTs$X2001-AMTs$X1950,
  AMTs$X2002-AMTs$X1950,
  AMTs$X2003-AMTs$X1950,
  AMTs$X2004-AMTs$X1950,
  AMTs$X2005-AMTs$X1950,
  AMTs$X2006-AMTs$X1950,
  AMTs$X2007-AMTs$X1950,
  AMTs$X2008-AMTs$X1950,
  AMTs$X2009-AMTs$X1950
)
```

Comment: Please provide a *minimal, self-contained, reproducible example*. See the help files in the raster package for how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

create a function that takes the minus of every layer equal to and after 1950 from 1950.

```
minus<-function(dd, cc) {
return(dd-cc)
}


#now use overlay() from raster to create this new raster object
change <- overlay(AMTs[[1:59]], AMTs$1950, fun=minus)
```

breakdown:
the x variable from overlay `AMTs[[1:59]]` is equal to `dd` from the `minus` function, and the y variable `AMTs$1950` is equal to `cc` from the `minus` function.